# From string library, template function doesnt work with int value?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, templates

I am trying to use Template from string. I have a directory with 100 csv files with data pertaining to each year.

For ex.:

```
yob1881.txt
yob1882.txt
yob1883.txt
yob1884.txt
yob1885.txt
```

Now i want to use template so that i can loop over all files. So i am using a range function like:

```
for year in range(1880,2011):
    template = Template(/name/year$year)
    template.substitute(year)
```

This is returning an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-85f21050945a> in <module>()
      2 filepath = tp('/pythonDataProjects/Loan Granting/names/yob$year.txt')
      3 year = '1880'
----> 4 print(filepath.substitute(year))

/Users/omkar/anaconda/lib/python3.5/string.py in substitute(*args, **kws)
    127             raise ValueError('Unrecognized named group in pattern',
    128                              self.pattern)
--> 129         return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
    130 
    131     def safe_substitute(*args, **kws):

/Users/omkar/anaconda/lib/python3.5/string.py in convert(mo)
    117             named = mo.group('named') or mo.group('braced')
    118             if named is not None:
--> 119                 val = mapping[named]
    120                 # We use this idiom instead of str() because the latter will
    121                 # fail if val is a Unicode containing non-ASCII characters.
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

I know what the error is. However, i am not getting how to resolve it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not assigning the substitution when calling `template.substitute(year)`. You need to format this like:

```
template.substitute(year=year)
```

Also, `substitute()` returns a new string, so you should either reassign this template or assign it to a new variable.

```
for year in range(1880,2011):
    template = Template("/name/year$year")
    template = template.substitute(year=year)

    # Or

    new_temp = template.substitute(year=year)
```

**Suggestion**

Is there a reason why you're not using the `format()` method? You can get the same results by doing

```
for year in range(1880,2011):
    template = "/name/yob{}.txt".format(year)
```

Comment: Thanks @A Mangoon. Glad for the error resolve. Unfortunately, the format()  sometimes causes readability issues, specially for a data science guy like me, who has dealt only with SAS and R in the past. Hence was trying to use template. Thanks for the reply, it helped me to get along with format() too!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the parameter as a named argument:

```
for year in range(1880, 2011):
    template = Template('/name/year$year')
    t = template.substitute(year=year)
```